# Delete outgoing message smtp queue

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp, iis-6

Is there a way of deleting locked files in mailroot\queue in IIS6 Smtp?

We've been having problems with a huge bulk of e-mail being sent, we have now resolved this but there are 6 e-mails stuck in the queue which I wish to delete.

I've tried stopping the service, but it is now stuck in a stopping state.

E-mails were previously being sent even when in stopping. But these last few seem to be blocking other e-mails in the pickup directory.

I have read about a tool called aqadmcli.exe, but have been unable to find a working download link. I'm hesitant to use anything other than from an authoritative site.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the SMTP service to disabled.
2. Reboot the server.
3. Delete the messages.
4. Set the SMTP service to Automatic.
5. Start the SMTP service.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty I hope we don't have to do that as we can't really restart the machine - but thanks for the last resort.

Comment: If the SMTP service won't stop then you probably have no choice but to reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

Although I was unable to clear the queue by hand, talking to our host killing the inetinfo.exe  process would take the service out of the stopping state. Though they did inform me that it's the same process used by the IIS Admin Service, but the machine this was on it wasn't a problem.

This took it out of the stopping state.

There are still items in the queue, but I think they are queued just because they won't send at all and perhaps they will end up in the badmail after a while.

It's definitely sending e-mail now, as I'm seeing them go through pickup.

So I'm not 100% sure if was sending e-mail before, as the queue didn't seem to effect it. But killing inetinfo.exe took the service out of the stopping state.